# Two questions of set theory: necessary and sufficient conditions for a subset of a poset to be centered, posets with noncentered linked subsets.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

$(1)\hspace{4pt}$  Let $\left\langle X,\leq\right\rangle$ be a poset, and let $Y\subseteq X$ with $Y\ne\emptyset$.  I’m trying to prove that $Y$ is centered—*i.e.*, $Y$ is a filterbase on $X$— if and only if any finite subset $Z\subseteq Y$ has a lower bound.  I’m not at all sure how to do this, so I would appreciate any sugggestions.

$(2)\hspace{4pt}$  I’m trying to find an example of a poset $\left\langle X,\leq\right\rangle$ such that $\exists Y\subseteq X$ with $Y$ linked—*i.e.*, pairwise compatible—but $Y$ not centered.  Again, I really don’t know how to do this, and I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What does this '*centered*' mean exactly?

Comment: (1) isn’t quite clear: do you mean that each finite $F\subseteq Y$ has a lower bound **in** $Y$? Because if so, I don’t see what you have to prove: that says that $Y$ is centred. Or is the difficulty going in the other direction, showing that if each two elements of $Y$ have a lower bound in $Y$, then every finite subset of $Y$ has a lower bound in $Y$? That’s just induction on the size of the finite set.

Comment: Unfortunately, the statement of the problem is ambiguous.  I’ll quote it directly here:
“A subset of a partial order is linked iff any pair of elements has a lower bound, and centered iff any finite set of elements has a lower bound.”

Comment: @Berci
A centered collection on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ such that the collection $\mathcal{B}^\supseteq:=\left\{A\subseteq X\Big|\exists B\in\mathcal{B}\hspace{4pt}\mathrm{s.t.}\hspace{4pt}A\supseteq B\right\}$ is a filter on $X$.

Comment: The question is a bit old, but regarding (1), this is not true in general. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3682231/30222 for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

(2) Let $\langle X,\le\rangle=\langle\wp(\{0,1,2\}),\subseteq\rangle$, and take $Y$ to be the right $3$-element subset of $X$.