# When can centered sets be extended to filters?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, filters

Suppose $(\mathcal O, \leq)$ is an arbitrary poset. Let us say that $\mathcal O$ is *compact* if every $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal O$ which is centered (any finite subset of $\mathcal C$ has a lower bound in $\mathcal O$) can be extended to a filter in $\mathcal O$.

This is equivalent to the condition that $\mathcal C$ is contained in a directed set (one containing lower bounds for all finite subsets).

For example, if $\mathcal O$ is a meet-semilattice, then it is compact --- it suffices to close $\mathcal C$ under meets.

Not every poset is compact: for instance, if we let $\mathcal O$ consist of the nonempty finite sets of integers and put $A\leq B$ when $A=B$ or $B\subseteq A$ and $B$ is a singleton, then the set $\mathcal C$ of singletons in $\mathcal O$ is centered, but it does not have any centered proper supersets (and it is not a filter).

I was wondering if there is some simpler criterion for this "compactness", or whether it has an established name?

Comment: What do you mean by claiming " We say that O is compact if ..."?  Speak for yourself only, I would not say that.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: It's a definition. I changed the wording to make it hopefully less ambiguous.

Comment: Can you prove this directed set is somehow minimal? If so, maybe pre-lettuce?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I suppose you mean pre-lattice? In any event, what kind of minimality do you have in mind, and what is a pre-lattice/lettuce?